# Rectangle Under Graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Does anyone know why this code doesn't work? I'm trying to put a rectangle under the curve, but for some reason it gives me a very odd response.

```
\doucmentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
  ymin=-5, ymax=10, ytick={-4,-2,...,10}, ylabel=$f(x)$,
  xmin=0, xmax=6, xtick={0,2,...,10}, xlabel=$x$,
  domain=0:6,samples=101, %added
]
\addplot[domain=0:6,blue,name path=A] {-0.25*x^3+2.5*x^2-8*x+10};
\coordinate (A) at (1,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1,4.25);
\coordinate (C) at (2,4.25);
\coordinate (D) at (2,0);
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--cycle;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\doucmentclass` is no valid LaTeX macro (but that's not the real error).

Comment: First, you have a typo: it should be `\documentclass{standalone}`. Second, `pgfplots` tells you that you are missing the `intersections`. Load it with `\usetikzlibrary{intersections}`. And if you use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` it should work.

Comment: .... or `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}`, which loads `intersections` and is perhaps more suitable given that you want to fill something with pgfplots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the things pointed out by @Skillmon and @Phelype Oleinik, you do not need `tkz-euclide` here, and the way you construct the rectangle is unnecessarily complicated. Furthermore, the rectangle won't show unless you set the compatibility to `1.11` or a newer version, or prepend the coordinates with `axis cs:`, but I'd prefer the first option. Since you are playing with pgfplots, I guess you may want to load `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}`, which loads `intersections` but allows you to do more things. At this point, of course neither of these libraries is used.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
  ymin=-5, ymax=10, ytick={-4,-2,...,10}, ylabel=$f(x)$,
  xmin=0, xmax=6, xtick={0,2,...,10}, xlabel=$x$,
  domain=0:6,samples=101, %added
]
\addplot[domain=0:6,blue,name path=A] {-0.25*x^3+2.5*x^2-8*x+10};
\coordinate (A) at (1,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1,4.25);
\coordinate (C) at (2,4.25);
\coordinate (D) at (2,0);
\draw (A)  rectangle (C);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]